# PK and Unique Constraint

Tags: sql-server

I have a table to hold Users Claims as follows (1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserClaims] (
  [UserAccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Type] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
  [Value] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserClaims] PRIMARY KEY ([UserAccountID], [Type], [Value])
)
```

And I have a second option for the same table (2):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserClaims] (
  [UserAccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserClaims_UserAccountId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserAccountId),
  [Type] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
  [Value] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_UserClaims_Value_Type_UserAccountID unique (Value, [Type], UserAccountID)
)
```

And I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersAccounts] (
  [UserAccountID] [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UsersAccounts_UserAccountId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserAccountId)
)
```

When I get a User I will always need to get all its Claims from UserClaims.

The UserAccountID is enough to identify all User Claims ...

In option (2) the UserAccountID is both a PK and a FK.

I need to be able to add the following rows to UserClaims:

UserAccountID = 2, Type = Role, Value = Editor

UserAccountID = 1, Type = Role, Value = Editor

UserAccountID = 1, Type = Role, Value = Member

UserAccountID = 1, Type = Name, Value = John

But I can't add  the following Claims:

UserAccountID = 1, Type = Role, Value = Editor

UserAccountID = 1, Type = Role, Value = Editor

I cannot have two rows completly equal. All the other combinations are possible.

My idea is to use (2). It is closer of what I am used to do ... What do you think?

Thank You!

Comment: In this case the UserClaims UserAccountID is the same as Users table UserAccountID which is identity. So when I get a User I also need to get its Claims. I will never get a Claim by itself. This is why I used UserAccountId ... So do I need to index it making it a PK? Or the Unique constraint is enough?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: IMHO you are confusing theory and implementation here A constraint is an **abstract** datamodelling concept, which *can be* implemented / enforced by an index (which is a concrete *physical* thing) (and it appears the MS and mysql documentation mixes them up, too)

Answer (score 3):

It all depends what is supposed to be you primary key :)
But most probably [UserAccountID] should be a primary key, so first solution is wrong. It enables you to insert multiple rows with same [UserAccountID] (differing by other two columns), which will generate doubled records on joins with other tables.

Comment: Oh, i missed the name of the table. In this case, both approaches are wrong. Second implies that the user can have only one claims, and first says that the user can only have one claim of the same type and amount, whis is also not valid in any business, I suppose.
So you don't actually need a unique/PK constraint on a table, I guess (unless your business logic states something else - what'would be the reason for that?).
I'd only add an index on [UserAccountId] to speed up queries, and maybe [ClaimId] int identity(1,1) with primary key.

Comment: A user can only have one Claim with the same Type and Value. A user can only have a claim of type Role with value Editor. Does it make sense? So that is why I have the Unique constraint for the 3 columns. I just updated my question to give more information.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is more useful, because you will probably use UserAccountID in WHEREs and JOINs a lot, so an index on it will make your queries more efficent.

Comment: But the two constraints will not do the same thing.

Comment: The first one also caters for using UserAccountID in WHEREs and JOINS as it is a clustered index starting with UserAccountID.

Comment: Is it true for every DBMS?

Comment: I will not have so many WHERE and JOINS queries. Basically, I get all Claimns (not more than 10) when I get one User.

Answer (score 2):

though in terms of constraints enforced, `PK` and `UNIQUE` both enforce column (or set of columns) to have unique values. But In logical terms, `primary key` is the one which lets you identify the record uniquely, rather than just maintaining the unique constraint on the column. There can only be one PK in a table, but can be multiple Unique keys.

**Its more about the context of usage:**

for example, you have a table `person (varchar ssn, varchar vehiclenumber, .....)` though the SSN and Vehicle numbers are meant to be unique, but since the table have info about the person, you would want the SSN to be PK and vehiclenumber to be unique.

on the otherhand, you have a table `VehicleInfo (varchar owner_SSN, varchar vehiclenumber, .....)`. even in this case SSN and Vehicle numbers are meant to be unique, but since in this case the table is vehicle, so here you would want to have vehiclenumber as `PK` and SSN to be `unique`

Comment: Usually, I like to always have a PK for each table ... And then use constraints. I am closer to use option (2) than (1). I just updated my code with more information.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the only two options, I would go for the first one as it captured all your design requirements:

- Enforce uniqueness.
- Performance.

The second table design also works but at the cost of extra overhead for maintaining two indexes.

As another alternative, I would actually normalise the UserClaims table further to have the following structure:

```
create table dbo.UserAccount
(
    UserAccountID   int not null primary key
)

create table dbo.Claim
(
    ClaimID     int             not null primary key
    , Type      nvarchar(150)   not null
    , Value     nvarchar(150)   not null
    , unique
    (
        Type, Value
    )
)

create table dbo.UserClaims 
(
    UserAccountID   int not null
    , ClaimID       int not null
    , primary key 
    (
        UserAccountID
        , ClaimID
    )
)
```

UPDATE - To answer your question more specifically, you would probably want to use the second one if you have a need to search for all user claims for a given value.

For example, show me all the users who are claiming above $200,000.

As you can see, table design really depends on your data model and what kind of business questions you are asking.

UPDATE - Given the additional info provided, it is now clearer what you are trying to ask. Here is my revised attempt at answering your question.

It basically boils down to what do you get from option (2) that you are not getting from option (1)? Nothing from what I can see.

You can definitely create a foreign key on UserAccountID in option (1):

```
alter table dbo.UserClaims
add constraint fk_UserClaims_UsersAccounts foreign key
(
    UserAccountID
)
references UsersAccounts
(
    UserAccountID
)
```

If you are searching by UserAccountID, clustered primary keys in both options will get you the result efficiently.

If you want to enforce uniqueness, the primary key in option (1) and the unique constraint/index in option (2) both does the job.

Comment: Hello, normalizing the Claims would be a good idea but in this case is not possible ... I will not have a way to normalize it.

Answer (score 1):

The PK cannot contain `NULL` values while the `UNIQUE` can. In this case you have `NOT NULL` fields, but keep in mind this substantial difference in all general cases. 
A second difference: every table has at most one `PK` (and allows n Foreign Keys) while you can set as many `UNIQUE` as you wish.

**Example**:
your table stores data about Sanitary Card (of U.S. Sanitary System) using these fields:

- card code
- user social security number (SSN)
- user first / last name

In this case your card code could be the PK of your system because your context is the Sanitary System, but you need to keep unique SSN too even if not in PK constraint. In fact, a PK of two fields (SSN and Card Code) allows the same SSN for different Card Code and the same Card Code for different SSN while we need to keep both unique. 
Generally, I use a field that identifies my record in a context as PK and the others as UNIQUE.

So if UserAccountID identifies your record you must set the field as PK and the others (VALUE,TYPE) as UNIQUE. Providing a table example we can be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. I would introduce a new field, specifically to be the primary key. I don't know your business logic for certain, but I think these three plausible scenarios all rule out option 1:

1. We recorded the claim against the wrong user, and need to correct it! (need to change the UserAccountID)
2. We recorded the claim with the wrong type, and need to correct it (you need to change the Type)
3. The claim's value has changed (you need to change the Value amount)

And this very plausible scenario rules out option 2:

1. The user has put in a second claim.

If *any* of those data items can change, ever, that means they're not suitable to use as your PK. Instead, just add a new auto-incrementing integer field to be the ClaimID. It takes up a little bit more space (a small downside), but the upside is that your natural data values are never artificially constrained by being part of a primary key.

Also, I would not add a uniqueness constraint on these three fields; for a similar reason, your natural data values might turn out to be not unique. For example if the user puts in a second claim, of the same type, for the same value (on a different date perhaps).